# How to say a data of type A is also of type B in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am learning haskell and am having trouble following the line of thought. I am trying to think in C++ terms and I am unable to find the equivalent of C++ subclass in Haskell. How do I say data B is also data A for simple structs A and B?

Background: I have read LearnYouAHaskell at least thrice. I am able to write basic Haskell code, but nothing very advanced and am fairly experienced working in C++.

Attempts: I was trying to think in terms of defining A as a type class and making B an instance of A. However, I don't want to write new definition of the method/data member and just want to use the definition of A. I am unable to comprehend the error messages.

```hs
-- Trial.hs 

class A a where 
    data_member :: Int 

data B = B { 
    x :: Int 
}

instance A B;
```

```
Trial.hs:2:9: error:
    • Could not deduce (A a0)
      from the context: A a
        bound by the type signature for:
                   data_member :: A a => Int
        at Trial.hs:2:9-26
      The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    • In the ambiguity check for ‘data_member’
      To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
      When checking the class method: data_member :: forall a. A a => Int
      In the class declaration for ‘A’
```

Comment: You don't say that data B is also data A in Haskell. Without further details about your *goals* (rather than the first *implementation plan* that comes to mind for fulfilling those goals), there's basically nothing more that can be said about alternatives.

Comment: Thank you. I have a system which I want to design as: 
class A { .... };
class B : public A {};
class C : public A {};
Where A has no functions, only data members. 

If this isn't doable in Haskell, how do we go about designing systems where this is  the way to do in C++? 

(Thanks for the reply again)

Comment: The Haskell approach is to throw out everything you've heard about object-oriented design and work from statements about data. What is the input? What's is the output? How do I transform between them?

Comment: There is no subtyping in Haskell like there is in C++. We might model that scenario by composition rather than inheritance, in C++ lingo. Values of type `B` will contain a value of type `A`, but will not be implicitly convertible to type `A`. A hard part of learning a new language is to avoid "thinking in the old language" and trying to apply the same idioms. Haskell and C++ are so radically different that learning any one after the other requires to retrain one's habits, requiring as much effort as if one were learning their very first programming language.

Comment: @Carl: Let me try to frame this differently - B has a lot of data members, C has a lot of data members and a very significant number of them is common. Further, I want to do: type Either B C = A and manipulate data with A, basically I will have a list of As and then, map some functions on that list. Pardon me if I am not making sense.

Comment: If `B` and `C` have a lot of common data, then why not create `D` that contains the common elements and `B` and `C` each contain a `D`?

Comment: @chi:  Thank you. I am trying to learn but somehow keep on getting stuck. I have some classes B, C, D all of them will contain A's data in that case by composition. Now, can I create a list of B, C ... D and map a function f on the underlying A in that way? How would you go about doing that.

Comment: A class in Haskell is *not* the same as a class in Java/C#/... it is more what would be an interface in Java. You `data_member` should problaby have type `a -> Int`. And you should furthermore specify that `data_member = x` to fix this, but that will likely not help you with what you aim to achieve.

Comment: @PratyushRathore *"map a function `f` on the underlying `A`"* remember, you *can't* modify a given value, only create a modified copy of it.

Comment: @WillNess: Yes. That I knew. Thanks :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like Damian suggests, use a Sum type: The `|` type operator/constructor.

Using ADT (Algebraic Data Types) is a great strength of Haskell. Dive blindlessly into using them whenever you can, I think all programmer learning haskell with an Imperative background come to this same conclusion: ADT are incredibly useful and concise.

Coming from a C++ background, when I first groked the Sum type I was translating it to C++ in my mind this way:

```
data PureVirtualClassA = ConcreteClassB Member1 Member2 | ConcreteClassC Member3
```

where Member1, Member2, and Member3 would be the types of a struct member. You can simplify this example with all the three being Int:

```
data PureVirtualClassA = ConcreteClassB Int Int | ConcreteClassC Int
```

(If you want a named data member, you should go for using Records, but they are not always needed)

Now you can use it in a function, just like you would use C++ polymorphism, where ConcreteClassB and ConcreteClassC would be deriving from PureVirtualClassA:

```
myFunction :: PureVirtualClassA -> Int
myFunction (ConcreteClassB x y) = x + y
myFunction (ConcreteClassC z) = z
```

IMPORTANT NOTE: In those examples for the C++ programmer I have used the word Class with the C++ meaning! Don't use the word Class this way in Haskell. A class in Haskell is something different, it's more like an interface, but the comparison does not stand.

Comment: Got it. It is the function which implements the virtual part of it. Though, I am not sure if I would not be confused tomorrow.

Comment: @PratyushRathore Haskell is different. Start using the words "Pattern Matching" and "Destructuring" instead of virtuality: it is different indeed. Here values of type PureVirtualA, can be destructured into a (ConcreteB x y) or a (ConcreteC z). This operation is called pattern match. Nothing beats training and repetition exercise: Do it on really small examples, several times, tomorrow or at some days of interval, and you will get it, I assure you. It is simpler than the C++ inheritance system. Much simpler. Play with it, your brain will get it. You can also think of it as an enhanced enum type

Comment: @StephaneRolland: Thanks. I am definitely going to put more time into it.

Comment: "enhanced enum type" a.k.a. [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union). :)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new type containing both:

```
data A = A Int
data B = B Int

data AB = MakeA A | MakeB B

:t MakeA $ A 4
MakeA $ A 4 :: AB
```